# Inject files as list of resources using wildcard by annotations in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations, spring-io

I have a class which I use as a spring bean. The bean is defined in the `applicationContext.xml` like:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.example.MyClass">
        <property name="cssFiles" value="classpath*:../../cssDir/*.css"/>
</bean>
```

And `MyClass` looks like:

```
...
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
...
public class MyClass {
    private List<Resource> cssFiles;

    // methods etc.
}
```

So Spring populates the cssFiles field with all the files with .css extension under **"classpath*:../../cssDir/"** .

Now I am working on moving to full annotation configuration, but I could not manage to do the same thing with annotations. This does NOT work:

```
...
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
...
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Value("classpath*:../../cssDir/*.css")
    private List<Resource> cssFiles;

    // methods etc.
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does it work like this: `@Value("classpath*:../../cssDir/*.css")
    private Resource[] cssFiles;`?

Comment: Thank man, it worked, you are a hero! Can you write this as answer so I can mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: Thank you Utku, just what I needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following, if you're willing to use an array instead of a `List`:

```
@Value("classpath*:../../cssDir/*.css")
private Resource[] cssFiles;
```

Comment: is there a way to construct this resource array in the xml config?

Answer (score 1):

For application.properties (yml) approach:

```
someFiles=file:/some/path/*.someExtension
```