# Spring resource loading using * (classpath*: prefix)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In Spring, bean initialization using XML supports resource loading using the `classpath*:` prefix (ant style)

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.Class"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="mappingFiles" value="classpath*:/mappings/*Mapping.xml" />
</bean>
```

How do I achieve the same result when using `@Bean` annotation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inject files as list of resources using wildcard by annotations in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738402/inject-files-as-list-of-resources-using-wildcard-by-annotations-in-spring)

Comment: Yes Andy it is duplication of the one you referred . let me know if i need to delete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any spring bean

```
@Value("classpath:myClasspathLocation") 
private Resource res;
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer , with this approach we can read single file at a time, we have number of files with prefix Mapping.xml, and to avoid unnecessary code we would like to use same approach as in     XML

Comment: Thank You again @Evgeni , below worked for me.  

         @Value("classpath*:/mappings/*Mapping.xml")
 private Resource[] resources;'