# Spring @Value using wildcard

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

Can I use wildcard in Spring `@Value`,as following ?

```
@Value("${key.*}) 

private String [] keys;
```

I want that above match all keys start with "key." word

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738402/inject-files-as-list-of-resources-using-wildcard-by-annotations-in-spring

Comment: Just try it - What happens?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov I used "keys.*"  but it doesn work for me.

Comment: @nickb It does not match my key.